# pip3 is not installed in centos7

Tags: pip, python-3.5, centos7

When I use the below command to install pip3 for python 3.5.1:

sudo yum -y install python35u-pip

Then I get the following issue:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.usonyx.net
 * extras: centos.usonyx.net
 * updates: centos.usonyx.net
No package python35u-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have used centos 7 and python 3.5.1 installed. I have googled so much but when didn't get any response from it then I came here for the suggestions and help.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong at any place

Comment: sudo yum -y install python35-pip works? without 'u'.
From my point of view there is a typo error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have a typing error, the right command should be

```
sudo yum -y install python35-pip
```

Please note the difference python35**u**-pip.

If this will raise other errors, try to follow this procedure:

```
$ sudo yum install python35-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install-3.5 pip
```

It needs to have the EPEL repository enabled.

Let me know.